# MySQL - Optimizing OR statement

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I want to search 3 columns using the `OR` clause.  I'm missing something simply, I know, but I keep getting a mysql error.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT customerid,companyname,firstname,lastname
FROM `tbl_customers` 
WHERE customeronoff = 1 
AND customerrecordtype = 'A' 
AND (companyname LIKE '$query%') OR (lastname LIKE '$query%') OR (firstname LIKE '$query%')   
ORDER BY lastname ASC
```

I must be placing the OR's wrong.  Would someone fix me, please

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use paranethesis to group your `OR` staements:

```
AND (
     (companyname LIKE '$query%') 
  OR (lastname LIKE '$query%') 
  OR (firstname LIKE '$query%')  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two parentheses:

```
SELECT customerid,companyname,firstname,lastname
FROM `tbl_customers` 
WHERE customeronoff = 1 
AND customerrecordtype = 'A' 
AND **(**(companyname LIKE '$query%') OR (lastname LIKE '$query%') OR (firstname LIKE '$query%')**)**
ORDER BY lastname ASC
```